# Postprocess when envelop is signed

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm using Docusign to create automatic envelopes but I want to save the signed envelope on my server. What's the best practice to do this?

Could I use the connect function? When yes, how will the request look like? (I can't find a documentation)

[Here my custom connect configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5mde.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using or if you're using the SDK but we have lots of resources on Connect and how to use it.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes shows you how to do that in all 6 SDK languagues.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application gives you some background about how to configure Connect webhooks

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect has all the information and code example for how to use Connect

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using Java and I already have a EventNotification setted up. When setting up the Event Notification I also have to declare an endpoint URL but how will the call to my server look like?

Comment: The call to your server would include an XML or JSON with the relevant information. See the links above for more details and try it out.